# How to implement AcousticEchoCanceler between TextToSpeech and SpeechRecognizer

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

My achievement is TextToSpeech will speak some paragraph, meanwhile SpeechRecognizer is listening for user input. If SpeechRecognition detect any text then TextToSpeech have to stop.

```
public class SpeechService : ISpeechRecognizer
 {
     protected Subject<bool> ListenSubject { get; } = new Subject<bool>();
     readonly object syncLock = new object();
     [Obsolete]
     public IObservable<string> Listen(Action action = null) => Observable.Create<string>(ob =>
          {
              speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.CreateSpeechRecognizer(Application.Context);
              var listener = new SpeechRecognitionListener(); 
              listener.ReadyForSpeech = () => this.ListenSubject.OnNext(true);
              listener.PartialResults = sentence =>
              {
                      if (action != null)
                      {
                          action.Invoke();
                      }
                      lock (this.syncLock)
                      {
                          sentence = sentence.Trim();
                          if (currentIndex > sentence.Length)
                              currentIndex = 0;
                          var newPart = sentence.Substring(currentIndex);
                          currentIndex = sentence.Length;
                          final = sentence;
                      }
          }
          listener.EndOfSpeech = () =>
          {
             ob.OnNext(final);
             ob.OnCompleted();
             this.ListenSubject.OnNext(false);
          }
          speechRecognizer.SetRecognitionListener(listener);
          speechRecognizer.StartListening(this.CreateSpeechIntent(true));
          return () =>
          {
              audioManager.SetStreamMute(Stream.Notification, false);
              stop = true;
              speechRecognizer?.StopListening();
              speechRecognizer?.Destroy();
              this.ListenSubject.OnNext(false);
          };
     });
     protected virtual Intent CreateSpeechIntent(bool partialResults)
     {
         var intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ActionRecognizeSpeech);
         intent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraLanguagePreference, Java.Util.Locale.Default);
         intent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraLanguage, Java.Util.Locale.Default);
         intent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraLanguageModel, RecognizerIntent.LanguageModelFreeForm);
         intent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraCallingPackage, Application.Context.PackageName);
         intent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraPartialResults, partialResults);
         return intent;
     }
 }
```

This my speech recognition calling

```
 public class MyViewModel : ReactiveObject
     {
         CancellationTokenSource textToSpeechCancellationToken;
         public MyViewModel ()
         {
             speak("Xamarin is a Microsoft-owned San Francisco-based software company founded in May 2011 by the engineers that created Mono, Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS, which are cross-platform implementations of the Common Language Infrastructure and Common Language Specifications.");
             Action actionAfterSpeechDetect = delegate
             {
                 if (textToSpeechCancellationToken != null && !textToSpeechCancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                 {
                     textToSpeechCancellationToken.Cancel();
                 }
             };
             using (var cancelSrc = new CancellationTokenSource())
             {
                 output = await DependencyService.Get<ISpeechRecognizer>().Listen(actionAfterSpeechDetect).ToTask(cancelSrc.Token);
             }    
         }
         public void speak(string text)
         {
             Task.Run(async () =>
             {
                 textToSpeechCancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
                 await TextToSpeech.SpeakAsync(text, textToSpeechCancellationToken.Token);
             });
         }
     }
```

For the above implementation, If I didn't speak anything then TextToSpeech is stopping. Because speech recognition detect text from speaker output. So, I would know about How to ignore mobile speaker output (TextToSpeech) for speech recognition in Xamarin Android.

I was found AcousticEchoCanceler, but I don't know how to implement the it with TextToSpeech and SpeechRecognizer.
Please Help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `UtteranceProgressListener` so you'll know when the voice has completed. You don't need to listen before that.

Comment: Hi, I want to break the TTS when the speech recognition detect text. I don't want to wait until TTS ends. But if I didn't spoke anything TTS need to end automatically.

Comment: @ThamotharanG If you want to speak over TTS voice and get detected, I am not aware any app does that (e.g. Google Assistant doesn't do that). The API that you have mentioned is not helpful for that and I am not aware anyone has made available to public something like that, so basically you will need to build a highly custom solution for that.